# Git windows server with Github

Tags: git, github

I'm fairly new to Git and was hoping someone can help me. We are working with an external provider and there code is on github which has a couple of branches (say branch1 and branch2). We plan on having a local Windows git server just using a bare repo and devs will be able to access this by just file share for now where they will clone, push, pull. Reason behind a local server is due to size.

What would be the best way to go about implementing, using this ? For example:
1. create a bare repo on our server - git init --bare
2. Add a remote to github name github
3. Fetch remote repo(from github)
4. User clones our local repo...
5. push/pull to our local...
6. how would you now merge our code into a branch on github?

Update:
Sorry, one other thing i forgot to mention is that we have only been granted pull access to github which we can't change due to the third party. We only get granted push access once everything is complete

Thanks

Comment: Will size *really* be an issue? The first clone will take some time. But after that, pushes and pulls should be fairly quick.

Comment: Yup, size is unfortunately an issue as each new person that works on it will have to grab it which takes hrs :(

Comment: Yes but that "grab" is a one time thing. Maintaining a synchronised mirror is overkill for that. If you really need to, clone from github once, create a bare repo somewhere, push to that and ask people to clone from that first time and from then onwards, use github as a remote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either set up a script to push the changes up to Github as they appear in the repository, or you could task someone with deciding when it's necessary and manually pushing changes from their own clone of your repo up to Github.  Remember that in a distributed environment, no particular repository has any technical reason to be different from any others: it's all convention.

One thing you should be careful of, though: using file shares, all changes in the repo on your server will be made directly by the user doing the pushing.  Even over a LAN, that might well be slower than talking to an intelligent server over the internet.  I've also had difficulty in the past pushing to remote Git repositories over SMB.  If it's at all possible, set up a server rather than just using file shares.  If that's not possible, test well and verify that you're actually getting better performance.

As stated in the comments, there's no reason to set up a synchronised mirror for people to do an initial get: remember that all the repositories will have the same data.  Rather than downloading the entire history every time, there's nothing stopping someone new from grabbing all the history from their colleague next to them, then pulling and pushing to Github.

Comment: Sorry, one other thing i forgot to mention is that we have only been granted pull access to github which we can't change due to the third party. We only get granted push access once everything is complete

Comment: Then you really want to be running your own service somewhere, rather than using a file share -- even just using https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-http-backend.html

Comment: Great, i'll do that. Once that's done would the process be sort of like this.

1. create bare repo on local server
2. fetch from github
3. on devmachines, clone the repo from the local server and push/pull to that server
4. then when all done, push to correct branch on github from one of the dev machines?

Comment: Pretty much, yes.  You may be able to combine steps one and two by cloning from Github.  Also, if you've got access to the server then there's nothing stopping you from doing four from there.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever size is an issue, don't forget that Git isn't a centralized VCS in which you can drop *everything* in it.

You should decompose your large set of files into several Git repo, allowing developers to clone/work only on some of those repos.

Any work on a file share should be avoided with Git: it *kills* performance...